# Download javax.json using maven

Tags: java, json, maven

I'm trying to use javax.json lib so I added it to my pom.xml file like that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

this inside the  tag. But when I try to run my project doing run as then putting the goal to "package" or "install", I'm expecting to see the json library inside my Maven dependencies lib like the others such as Junit. But I don't see anything. So if you have an idea about where the problem could come, thanks to let me know.

PS:I'm new to the maven thing.

EDIT:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building RssApp Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ RssApp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ RssApp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ RssApp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\trist_000\Eclipse\RssApp\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ RssApp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ RssApp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ RssApp ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [RssApp] in     [C:\Users\trist_000\Eclipse\RssApp\target\RssApp]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources             [C:\Users\trist_000\Eclipse\RssApp\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [75 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\trist_000\Eclipse\RssApp\target\RssApp.war
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.751 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-27T01:53:10+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/119M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: do you get any messages during build/package lifecycles?  can you add a section about the `<build>` tag?

Comment: I did that : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api/1.0
I'm gonna add the message during the build

Comment: I also checked, looks correct... any output messages?

Comment: @ochi is correct, there may be any errors in the build's output. I would like to add: After doing sth. like `mvn clean install`, do you get `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` at the end?
Also, did you actually try to use javax.json classes in your project? Maybe there's nothing wrong at all.

Comment: _"I'm expecting to see the json library inside my Maven dependencies lib like the others such as Junit. But I don't see anything"_ Can you explain how you're checking this? Are you looking somewhere in your filesystem (if so, where?) or checking something inside your IDE, or inside a war file?

Comment: and the .jar file is not inside the generated WAR File? you checked, right?

Comment: I checked in my IDE inside the "Maven Dependencies" which is in "Libraries" which is in "Java Resources", and then yes I tryed to import it without success. Where can I checked for the WAR file ?

Comment: mvn will not necessarily tell your IDE what your project's dependencies are (unless you configured it as a mvn project, depends on your IDE as well).  Anyhow, check your target folder for the WAR file - should be in there (full path is in the output: `C:\Users\trist_000\Eclipse\RssApp\target\RssApp.war`)

Comment: Yes I have the war file but how can I check what is inside ? how can I use javax.json with it ? Yes I did a Maven project and I'm using Eclipse

Comment: Unzip the WAR file, check the WEB-INF/lib folder inside - As for how to use the JSON library, that's up to you (separate question) - why are you adding it if you do not need it?

Comment: Ok the the lib is inside my .war file. But when i'm coding I would like to use it. So I try to import it like that "import javax.json" but it does not work. I cant create an object JsonObject.

Comment: @Tritri `javax.json.JsonObject` is an Interface, so you cannot create an object `JsonObject`. Are you able to call `JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader("[]"));` though?

Comment: Thanks but I can't even import javax.json. It does not look inside the war file. There is something I don't understand with maven I think lol.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you have to right-click the project and select "Maven.... Update Project" and the newly added libraries in your pom.xml file will be downloaded to your libraries directory.